# React Three Drei Environment doesn't seem to allow adjusting of intensity

Tags: 3d, react-three-drei

I have been playing a bunch with the Environment component and I've decided instead of using images I would just use colors to set the mood and theme I need. I originally tried using Ambient lights which worked fine but I import models from Blender with metallic materials and ambient light doesn't work on them it seems while using Environment set to a color does. However, I can not find an option to adjust the intensity of the Environment color. Is there an option?

```
<Environment>
        <color args={[sun_color]} attach="background" />
      </Environment>
```

I've tried adding "intensity" in a variety of places and can't seem to find an option anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
const texture = useLoader(RGBELoader, 'xxx.hdr')
```

then try this:

```
<Environment background={false} blur={0}>
   <color attach="background" args={['black']} />
   <mesh rotation={[0, 0, 0]} scale={5}>
   <sphereGeometry />
   <meshBasicMaterial transparent opacity={0.4} map={texture} side={THREE.BackSide} toneMapped={false} />
   </mesh>
</Environment>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Clarifying the previous answer on this thread, you will need to add mesh and a material component and give it texture so the metallic material you added can reflect the lights. There are great examples on YouTube - just type React Three Fiber & Three.js - Materials Explained

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35745922)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Three.js and you want to adjust the intensity of the color set in the Environment component, you can achieve this by manipulating the color's RGB values.

***Here's how you can adjust the intensity of the color:***

```
import { Environment } from '@react-three/drei';
import { Color } from 'three';
```

// Define your color with RGB values

```
const sunColor = new Color(1, 0.5, 0); // Example color: orange
```

// Adjust the intensity by multiplying the RGB values by a factor

```
const intensity = 0.5; // Example intensity factor
```

// Multiply the RGB values by the intensity factor

```
sunColor.multiplyScalar(intensity);
```

// Now you can use the adjusted color with the Environment component

```
<Environment>
  <color attach="background" args={[sunColor]} />
</Environment>
```

In this example, I've set the color to orange (you can adjust the RGB values as needed), and then I've adjusted its intensity by multiplying its RGB values by a factor (intensity variable). This way, you can control the intensity of the color effectively. Adjust the intensity value according to your needs to control how intense the color appears in your scene.